# Get dynamic class each fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can get(dynamic) each class `fieldset` that wrapping the elements in it?

**Like:**

if click on button `adult` =get class=> `.adult` from here in the html: `<fieldset class="adult">`
if click on button `child wbed` =get class=> `.child wbed` from here in the html: `<fieldset class="child wbed">`
if click on button `child bed` =get class=> `.child bed` from here in the html: `<fieldset class="child bed">`
if click on button `baby` =get class=> `.baby` from here in the html: `<fieldset class="baby">`

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WErW9/7/

```
$('button').live("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).remove();
    var $this = $(this),
        $div = $this.parent('fieldset');
    var name = '.' + $(this).closest('fieldset').attr("class");
    alert(name);
});
```

Comment: Please HTML code does not change. Which div? please give me example in http://jsfiddle.net/WErW9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('button').live("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this), $div = $this.closest('fieldset');
    var name = '.' + $div.attr("class");
    alert(name);
});
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/WErW9/4/) ]**</sup>

Comment: If adding `$(this).remove();`, it don't worked!? what do i do? see: http://jsfiddle.net/WErW9/5/

Comment: Well, its like: "If you would jump into a net and while jumping, remove the net...why doesn't the net catch you?" For the record, you didn't mention `remove()` anywhere in your question, however, it doesn't work because the order is incorrect: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/WErW9/6/ The idea is that, you want to remove it AFTER, you get the data..not before, or there wouln't be anything from where to get the data..

Comment: Yes, that's right but i want remove before not after. did you can help for this? http://jsfiddle.net/WErW9/5/

Comment: Or maybe you simply want to hide your element and then check its class? In that case you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/WErW9/8/

Comment: you change location `$(this).remove();`, but i not want change location `$(this).remove();`. is true location it in here: http://jsfiddle.net/WErW9/5/. how is for this?

Comment: did can not done with `remove()` no `hide()`? must use of `remove()`

Comment: Remove = Deletes the element. Means **you cannot use something that is deleted**. You can however hide it and then understand its class with your original position: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/WErW9/8 This way, the element keeps existing, but is not visible..sort of like remove.